# Python Поиск соседних элементов в матрице, некорректный вывод

Tags: python, python-3.x

Новичок, делаю первые шаги в программировании. Задача: получить на выводе соседние элементы в матрице по заданным координатам. Написал такой код:

```
li = []
m = int(input('m'))
n = int(input('n'))
i = int(input('i'))
j = int(input('j'))

for i in range(0, m):
    ele = list(map(int, input().split()))
    li.append(ele)

def get_adjacent_indices(i, j, m, n):
  n_list = []
  if i > 0:
    n_list.append((li[i-1][j]))
  if i + 1 < m:
    n_list.append((li[i+1][j]))
  if j > 0:
    n_list.append((li[i][j-1]))
  if j + 1 < n:
    n_list.append((li[i][j+1]))
  return sorted(n_list)

print(get_adjacent_indices(i, j, m, n))
```

Код работает исправно, если список с вложенными списками заранее объявить в переменной **li**, если же использовать ввод, то результат будто смещается, и получаю неверный результат. Например, при **li = [[1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 6], [8, 4, 2], [3, 7, 1]]** правильный вывод будет **[2, 2, 7, 8]**, если использовать ввод, то **[1, 3, 4]**. Почему так происходит? Как исправить код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

уф - нашел ваше ошибку!!!

```
def get_adjacent_indices(i, j, m, n):

  print(i, j, m, n) # посмотрим, что на вход получает функция
```

и смотрим что выводится - `2 1 4 3` если использовать подготовленные данные и `3 1 4 3` - если вводить с клавиатуры

а дело все в цикле

```
for i in range(0, m):
```

который тоже использует `i` и эта `i` потом идет на вызов функции

```
print(get_adjacent_indices(i, j, m, n)
```

но значение этой `i` уже не то, которое вводилось пользователем, а то которое она получила на последнем этапе цикла `for i in range(0, m):`, т.е. `m`

используйте другую переменную или вообще так:

```
for _ in range(0, m):
    ele = list(map(int, input().split()))
    li.append(ele)
```

и все заработает

P.S.

`li` кстати можно и в 1 строчку было бы определить:

```
li = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(m)]
```

Comment: Честь и хвала!!